# How do I install Eclipse for C

Tags: c

How do I install Eclipse for C
Please send links and helpful tips.
Thanks

Need an easy install
• Steps involved
• SDK with all the libraries and stuff I'll need
• Variable path setup
• Anything else that may surprise a noob

Comment: When you say "C Basic" do you just mean C?

Comment: @Mike Daniels, I mean C, oopse:)

Comment: @Mike Daniels: Like "pocket watch", I think... They were just called watches, until wrist watches caught on. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following plug-in which allows me to develop in both C and C++
[Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

There are tutorials and instructions on how to download on the website, so if you have any other questions, let me know!

Comment: it's asking me to instal a toolbell, Gygwin etc. @daveangel was right about it not being a easy and clear install.

Comment: I assume then that you're running Windows?  I'll try to make this as easy as possible. 
I'm actually using MinGw's version of 'make' for developing. A link to the auto installer of MingGW can be found here if interested: http://sourceforge.net/downloads/mingw/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/MinGW%205.1.6/MinGW-5.1.6.exe/ 
After installing that, in Eclipse, I selected Project->Properties->C/C++ Build. You will see under 'Builder Settings' that there is an option for 'Build command'. In the build command, I use 'C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe'(no quotes) to allow me to compile in C. Hope this helps

Comment: Update: I was just stumbling upon some of my favorite links and happened to find one on "HOW TO: Use CDT and MinGW for Eclipse (i.e. develop C/C++ applications in windows)" Hopefully this will help you, as it has nice steps for setting up your environment! http://yongshin.blogspot.com/2005/11/how-to-use-cdt-and-mingw-for-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Eclipse for C or C++ (I have only used it for Java) and I'm guessing its just a simple install: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliosr
As far as I know, everything you'll need comes pre-packaged and configures itself as part of the installation. You'll need the [JRE](http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp) if you don't have it though.

Comment: thanks. I've done some of the Java installs is why I ask. Could it really be that simple?

Comment: Well the commenter below says there are some config details that are screwy. I'm donwloading the C/C++ version and seeing how it works myself. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Alright, I went through and installed everything and just tried a simply Hello, World! program and it was acting all wacked out.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest going with MS Visual C++ express instead especially if you are on Windows. The reason is that getting the GNU C compiler installed with Eclipse on Windows is a real pain.
I did it once and don't even remember since it's a bit of work to get Cygwin — which provides a Linux®-like environment on Windows installed. Not as easy and clear as it should be i.e. not just a point and click install like Eclipse with Java. I have a feeling not many people try installing it on Windows since the install documentation seems more geared towards the Linux where with many distro's gcc is already installed or a simple install.